# X server not starting anymore

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xorg, display-driver

I recently updated my arch Linux system and now I can't start the X server anymore. 
I don't use a graphical login screen but run startx automatically after login in.

Since the update I only get an error message and the computer freezes, without running a graphical environment.

This is the xorg.0.log file:

```
[ 393.882] X.Org X Server 1.19.3
Release Date: 2017-03-15
[ 393.882] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 393.882] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.11-1-ARCH x86_64 
[ 393.882] Current Operating System: Linux yoga-510-arch 4.11.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun May 28 10:40:17 CEST 2017 x86_64
[ 393.883] Kernel command line: initrd=\intel-ucode.img initrd=\initramfs-linux.img root=UUID=b0c31b50-c336-4e3e-866b-be816a2fa200 rootfstype=ext4 add_efi_memmap rw
[ 393.883] Build Date: 07 April 2017 05:42:48PM
[ 393.883] 
[ 393.883] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[ 393.883]  Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 393.883] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 393.884] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jun 10 00:07:18 2017
[ 393.888] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 393.888] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 393.890] (==) No Layout section. Using the first Screen section.
[ 393.890] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[ 393.890] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[ 393.890] (**) | |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[ 393.890] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[ 393.890] (==) Automatically adding devices
[ 393.890] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 393.890] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 393.890] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[ 393.890] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[ 393.892] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1/" does not exist.
[ 393.892]  Entry deleted from font path.
[ 393.893] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/misc/,
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/OTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/100dpi/,
    /usr/share/fonts/75dpi/
[ 393.893] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[ 393.893] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[ 393.893] (II) Loader magic: 0x822d60
[ 393.893] (II) Module ABI versions:
[ 393.893]  X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[ 393.893]  X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[ 393.893]  X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[ 393.893]  X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[ 393.894] (++) using VT number 1

[ 393.894] (--) controlling tty is VT number 1, auto-enabling KeepTty
[ 393.895] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c2
[ 393.896] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[ 393.896] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 11 paused 0
[ 393.897] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[ 400.237] (EE) systemd-logind: failed to take device /dev/dri/card1: Message recipient disconnected
```

How can I solve that problem, or just figure out the exact reason for it?

Comment: Do you have updated (or installed, if the package name changed) the X video drivers as well? From the log, it doesn't even attempt to load video drivers. If your video card needs DRM or a framebuffer, does the corresponding kernel module work?

Comment: I did a complete system update, so I think the x video drivers are up to date, too.
I solved the problem by deactivating my AMD GPU in the BIOS, only using the intel chipsets. But this is not a good solution since I can't use my GPU anymore.

Comment: I vaguely remember the AMD GPU drivers changed name and/or API at some stage. Definitely check out what packages you need under your current version of Arch. A "complete system update" does not necessarily install these.